# How can I restore a revision through the MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, ee, versioning

Is it possible to restore a previous version of a channel entry through the DB using phpMyAdmin? If so, where in the DB would I do that?

My client's assigns are entering things in Matrix fields with bad characters like quotes and dollar signs, and it is causing errors. (And these people are school teachers!) And, it makes the entry unable to be edited.

Many thanks in advance.

---

"bad characters like quotes and dollar signs ... causing errors ...makes the entry unable to be edited"

When they click on the entry in the CP it just generates an error, the entry does not some up.

I also can not see the entry in the MySQL DB, but I can see the previous version. I thought if I could find out how to restore that by working only with the DB I could fix it.

---

Thanks for that, @jrothafer, sorry for the noobie-ness.

No, the entry form for this entry does not open in the Control Panel, and the data for this part of the entry is in a Matrix channel field and would be in matrix_data (or something similar). But I think it is corrupted because I cannot find it.

Also, I noticed the client's person deleted the entry and recreated it, so all of this is not so important now. But it would be good to now as the data entry people have been making this mistake once in a while.

Comment: Why aren't you restoring it in the Control Panel in the regular fashion?

Comment: Does the entry form for this entry open in the Control Panel? Can you find the entry in the `channel_data` table? FYI, unless you add @jrothafer in your question edits, I don't get a notification that you edited your question.